# Does .net/C# have an equvilent Javascript Object Proxy/Serialization like DWR in Java?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, dwr

I have some old code in Javascript that interfaces to [Java DWR](https://dwr.dev.java.net/).  I'm looking to port the back-end to .NET/C# possibly, and I was just wondering if there was an equivalent AJAX framework that would work in the same manner as the DWR framework in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) seems close.